# How to write new line to file in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I would like to separate my data with `new line` character in an output file, but the following codes result in error "can't resolve overload for procedure call":

```
write(out_line, "\n"); 
write(out_line, ""); 
write(out_line, '');
```

An example code how I want to use it:

```
ENTITY writer IS 
PORT ( clk : IN STD_LOGIC := '0'; start : IN STD_LOGIC := '0');
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE arch OF writer IS
    SIGNAL vect : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) := "000";
    TYPE state_type IS (init, write_file);
    SIGNAL state : state_type := init;
BEGIN
    PROCESS (clk, start)
        FILE out_file : text;
        VARIABLE out_line : line;
    BEGIN
       IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
           CASE state IS 
               WHEN init => 
                   IF start = '1' THEN
                       state <= write_file;
                   ELSE 
                       state <= init;
                   END IF;
               WHEN write_file =>
                   state => init;

                   FOR i IN 0 TO 10 LOOP
                       write(out_line, vect);
                       writeline(out_file, out_line);
                       -- write(out_line, "\n"); <-- 
                       -- write(out_line, ""); <-- 
                       -- write(out_line, ''); <-- None of these work
                       writeline(out_file, out_line); 
                   END LOOP;
           END CASE;
       END IF;
   END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

So I would like to know, is it possible in VHDL? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will consistently give you a single blank line:

```
write(out_line, string'(""));  
writeline(out_file, out_line);
```

I suspect what @Dani posted may be tool dependent.   For example while on one popular simulator, the following produces one line feed:

```
write(out_line, LF);  
writeline(out_file, out_line);
```

However when I add a space after the LF, I get two lines:

```
write(out_line, LF & ' ');  
writeline(out_file, out_line);
```

Comment: If out_line hasn't been allocated,  been deallocated (deallocate call or writeline) you'd get a blank line  with a subsequent writeline - "If parameter L contains a null access value at the start of the call, then a null string is written to the file or files." (Same in -1993.) Does this work for your 'one popular simulator'? It'd keep from having any characters on a supposedly blank line.  Note the OP's code as shown has intervening write procedures commented out and should produce a blank line for the second procedure writeline in the for loop. Perhaps the 'one  popular simulator' was used?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a minimal, complete and verifiable example from the question's incomplete sample code:

```vhdl
library ieee;  -- ADDED
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  -- ADDED
use std.textio.all;  -- ADDED
-- use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;  -- ADDED for revisions earlier than -2008

ENTITY writer IS 
-- PORT ( clk : IN STD_LOGIC := '0'; start : IN STD_LOGIC := '0');
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE arch OF writer IS
    SIGNAL vect : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) := "000";
    -- TYPE state_type IS (init, write_file);
    -- SIGNAL state : state_type := init;

BEGIN
    PROCESS -- (clk, start)
        FILE out_file : text;
        VARIABLE out_line : line;
    BEGIN
      file_open(out_file, "some_file", WRITE_MODE);  -- ADDED
       -- IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
--            CASE state IS
--                WHEN init =>
--                    IF start = '1' THEN
--                        state <= write_file;
--                    ELSE
--                        state <= init;
--                    END IF;
--                WHEN write_file =>
--                    state => init;

                   FOR i IN 0 TO 10 LOOP
                       write(out_line, vect);
                       writeline(out_file, out_line);
                       -- write(out_line, "\n"); <-- 
                       -- write(out_line, ""); <-- 
                       -- write(out_line, ''); <-- None of these work
                       writeline(out_file, out_line); 
                   END LOOP;
           -- END CASE;
       -- END IF;
       wait;  -- ADDED
   END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

demonstrates a way to get a blank line in the output:

some_file contents:

```
000

000

000

000

000

000

000

000

000

000

000
```

The second `writeline` procedure call produces an empty line without an intervening `write` procedure call.

Why is seen in IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.4 Package TEXTIO:

> Procedures READLINE, WRITELINE, and TEE declared in package TEXTIO read and write entire lines of a file of type TEXT. Procedure READLINE causes the next line to be read from the file and returns as the value of parameter L an access value that designates an object representing that line. If parameter L contains a non-null access value at the start of the call, the procedure may deallocate the object designated by that value. The representation of the line does not contain the representation of the end of the line. It is an error if the file specified in a call to READLINE is not open or, if open, the file has an access mode other than read-only (see 5.5.2). **Procedures WRITELINE and TEE each cause the current line designated by parameter L to be written to the file and returns with the value of parameter L designating a null string.** Procedure TEE additionally causes the current line to be written to the file OUTPUT. **If parameter L contains a null access value at the start of the call, then a null string is written to the file or files.** If parameter L contains a non-null access value at the start of the call, the procedures may deallocate the object designated by that value. It is an error if the file specified in a call to WRITELINE or TEE is not open or, if open, the file has an access mode other than write-only.
>
> The language does not define the representation of the end of a line. An implementation shall allow all possible values of types CHARACTER and STRING to be written to a file. However, as an implementation is permitted to use certain values of types CHARACTER and STRING as line delimiters, it might not be possible to read these values from a TEXT file.
>
> A line feed (LF) format effector occurring as an element of a string written to a file of type TEXT, either using procedure WRITELINE or TEE, or using the WRITE operation implicitly defined for the type TEXT, is interpreted by the implementation as signifying the end of a line. The implementation shall transform the LF into the implementation-defined representation of the end of a line.
>
> ...
>
> For each WRITE, OWRITE, and HWRITE procedure, after data is appended to the string value designated by the parameter L, L designates the entire line. The procedure may modify the value of the object designated by the parameter L at the start of the call or may deallocate the object.

If deallocation occurs `out_line` will have a value of null after a `writeline` call and a null string is written in the immediately following `writeline` call which also provides an end of line.

If the object value accessed by `out_line` is a null array (having no elements, 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges, a null string) the immediately following `writeline` call will result in an end of line being written to the file.

In essence your code example already contains one of these methods for writing a blank line, which depends on whether deallocation is used conditionally (may).

Variants of allocate() and free() can be relatively expensive in terms of execution time and when the size of the allocated object and it's element size is known a smaller 'allocated' object can be written to the same object space saving simulation time. The simulation kernel representation of an array object can have bounds separate from the array value, deallocation and re-allocation can be reserved for when the object size is larger than the previously allocated size or an explicit `deallocate` call occurs.

There's also a requirement that an implementation translate an LF character to an end of line in a write to a file. This is the other mechanism that allows you to write an LF character as the last or only character to a line and get a following blank line.

You could also explicitly write a null string to `out_line`

```vhdl
         write(out_line, string'(""));
```

prior to the second `writeline` call. The qualified expression provides the type of the string literal unlike the attempt commented out in the original question where the type of the string literal can't be determined. See 9.3.2 Literals "... The type of a string or bit string literal shall be determinable solely from the context in which the literal appears, excluding the literal itself but using the fact that the type of the literal shall be a one-dimensional array of a character type. ...". The procedure `write` would be ambiguous in this context, failing overload resolution (12.5 The context of overload resolution).

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a lot of searching and trying I found that the following code works:

```
write(out_line, lf);  
writeline(out_file, out_line);
```

I found that `write(out_line, cr);` does the same thing, and `write(out_line, nul);` adds `' '` character between the outputs.

Comment: The authoritative place to look would be the IEEE Std 1076 (here -2008) 
16.4 Package TEXTIO "A line feed (LF) format effector occurring as an element of a string written to a file of type TEXT, either using procedure WRITELINE or TEE, or using the WRITE operation implicitly defined for the type TEXT, is interpreted by the implementation as signifying the end of a line. The implementation shall transform the LF into the implementation-defined representation of the end of a line.." LF is the enumeration name for the value of a linefeed (16.3 Package STANDARD, type CHARACTER declaration).

Comment: @user1155120  Why don't I get 2 line feeds for the above code.  One for LF and one for writeline?    For example, if I were to instead do "write(out_line, lf & ' ') ;" and then do the Writeline I would certainly get 2 line feeds.    I suspect it is because one vendor has a curious behavior when LF is the last character in a line.